# Is there any Tag for generating a datagrid in Struts 2?

Tags: struts2, grid

I need to generate a datagrid using a Struts 2, i have found out Struts-Layout can do that, but its not supporting Struts 2. Can any one suggest me a way to generate a datagrid using Struts 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two out of the box solution available.

The first is Display Tag and the other is [Struts2 jQuery Plugin with the Grid Tag][2].

http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/
http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/